# Confused about Panda syntax concerning `loc`

Tags: pandas

I heard that `loc` supports boolean array inputs instead of labels. If the arrays are too short, `loc` assumes the missing values are False.
However, when trying the syntax `elections.loc[[True, False, False, True], [True, False, False, True]]`, it returns an error like `IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 4 instead of 23`.

Is this function abolished in newer version? I am really confused.

I genuinely someone who got to know this telling about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, Pandas does not allow "short" masks.

Tested on versions 0.25.3, 1.2.5, 1.4.4, 1.5.3 and 2.0.2, the error is always:

```
IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 4 instead of 23

# Or for older versions

IndexError: Item wrong length 4 instead of 23.
```

Reproducible error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

elections = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((23, 4)))  # or (4, 23)
elections.loc[[True, False, False, True], [True, False, False, True]]
```

Comment: So do you remember exactly what is your use case?